# Magento 2 Dynamic cronjob

Tags: magento2, configuration, magento-cron

i'm trying to create dynamic cronjob based on my configuration value.
already created group defined in cron_groups.xml

and defined cron task

```
<group id="mycompany">
    <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Task" method="execute" name="custom_task">
        <config_path>tab/group/field</config_path>
    </job>
</group>
```

Most strange thing is if i use * * * * * as input value in admin config then i do see my task in cronjob table.

but when i set specific time like 0 0 * * * i don't see it there.

any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Magento uses a five value specification for a cron job. The numbers per each * * * * * is as follows:**
>
> Minute (0-59) For all Start environments and Pro Integration
>   environments, the minimum frequency supported for crons is five
>   minutes. You may need to configure settings in your Magento Admin.
>
> Hour (0-23)
>
> Day of month (1 - 31)
>
> Month (1 - 12)
>
> Day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday; 7 is also Sunday on some
>   systems)

```
  * * * * * command to be executed
  | | | | |
  | | | | +----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
  | | | +------- Month (1 - 12)
  | | +--------- Day of month (1 - 31)
  | +----------- Hour (0 - 23)
  +------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

Comment: wel it seem to be time problem. there is 2 hours difference between time i set and the time it was executed..